# Display form validations on form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, validation

I am trying to implement a simple newsletter registration form in which the user enters his email, and presses 'submit'. The email is stored in the MySQL database, and I would like to send a confirmation email to the subscriber.

I started with the code on https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Ajax-PHP-MySQL-Newsletter.
For some reasons, on submit, the validation result is shown on a new empty html page, while I would like to display the confirmation/validation on the initial page itself (on the form, as in the demo : http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/uploads/ajax-newsletter/

This is my HTML code:

```
    <div id="newsletterform">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <h3>Get Email Update</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
                    <form action="php/send.php" method="post" id="newsletter" name="newsletter">
                        <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Insert email here" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="signup-button" id="signup-button">
                        <span class="arrow"></span>
                    </form>
                    <div id="response"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the < head >, I have

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">
    <meta property="og:description" content="">
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/flickity.css" media="screen">



        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib.js"></script>
</head>
```

My Send.php

```
   <?php
        require 'Database.class.php';
        require 'Newsletter.class.php';

        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $email = $_POST['signup-email'];

            Newsletter::register($email);
        }
```

My Database.class.php

```
        <?php
class Database
{
    private static $dbName = '';
    private static $dbHost = '';
    private static $dbUsername = '';
    private static $dbUserPassword = '';

    private static $cont = null;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect() {
        if (null === self::$cont) {
            try {
                self::$cont =  new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$dbHost.'; dbname='.self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect() {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
```

My Newsletter.class.php

```
<?php
class Newsletter
{
    private static $email;
    private static $datetime = null;

    private static $valid = true;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function register($email) {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            self::$email    = $_POST['signup-email'];
            self::$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            if (empty(self::$email)) {
                $status  = "error";
                $message = "The email address field must not be blank";
                self::$valid = false;
            } else if (!filter_var(self::$email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $status  = "error";
                $message = "You must fill the field with a valid email address";
                self::$valid = false;
            }

            if (self::$valid) {
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $existingSignup = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM signups WHERE signup_email_address='$email'");
                $existingSignup->execute();
                $data_exists = ($existingSignup->fetchColumn() > 0) ? true : false;

                if (!$data_exists) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date) VALUES (:email, :datetime)";
                    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                    $q->execute(
                        array(':email' => self::$email, ':datetime' => self::$datetime));

                    if ($q) {
                        $status  = "success";
                        $message = "You have been successfully subscribed";
                    } else {
                        $status  = "error";
                        $message = "An error occurred, please try again";
                    }
                } else {
                    $status  = "error";
                    $message = "This email is already subscribed";
                }
            }

            $data = array(
                'status'  => $status,
                'message' => $message
            );

             echo json_encode($data);

            Database::disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

and my lib.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newsletter').submit(function () {
        var $this     = $(this),
            $response = $('#response'),
            $mail     = $('#signup-email'),
            testmail  = /^[^0-9][A-z0-9._%+-]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/,
            hasError  = false;

        $response.find('p').remove();

        if (!testmail.test($mail.val())) {
            $response.html('<p class="error">Please enter a valid email</p>');
            hasError = true;
        }

        if (hasError === false) {

            $response.find('p').remove();
            $response.addClass('loading');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: $this.attr('action'),
                data: $this.serialize()
            }).done(function (data) {
                $response.removeClass('loading');
                $response.html('<p>'+data.message+'</p>');
            }).fail(function() {
                $response.removeClass('loading');
                $response.html('<p>An error occurred, please try again</p>');
            })
        }


        return false;
    });
});
```

I have been searching for hours why the validation messages are not shown on the page itself. When I submit with a wrong email address for example, the error message is shown on a new blank window "{"status":"error","message":"The email address field must not be blank"}"

Can someone help me out?
I'm not an experienced coder, so if s.o. can correct my code, I would be very gratefull.
I also have no clue how to trigger an email to the user confirming his registration... :/

Anna.

Comment: You need to include jquery before `lib.js`

Comment: eg `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Steve. I tried this but it did not change the behavior.. :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Reducing your posted example to the minimum necessary size to recreate the problem is a good debugging exercise for you, and draws more people to try your problem.

Comment: What he means, is that you have altogether too much code.  Try to find the smallest piece of code which will still produce the error, then post *that*, instead of dumping code here.  The community at Stack Overflow appreciates it when they can tell you put effort into it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to follow this rule. But in this problem, I have no clue in which part of the code the problem lies... :(  In my HTML code? php code? js code? :/

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have imported Jquery into your script and also on the submit event you have to prevent the default behavior of the form which is submit and refresh the page, you can do this with :

```
$('#newsletter').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code goes here.
```

Sorry for my bad english I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi jarguez01. I presumed I had to replace the second line of my lib.js with your piece of code. Also this seemed not to work. I still land on a new page on which the validation result is shown... :/

Comment: @user3981693 Can you please show the head of your html file? and also where are you including the jsquery lib?

Comment: I copy/pasted my <head> of my html file in my original post... :-)

Comment: Hi @user3981693 What error are you getting on the developers tools console in your browser.?

Comment: Hi. I don't see any error in the console. I just see the message I receive in my browser ({"status":"error","message":"The email address field must not be blank"}) and in Sources, I see Send.php ...

Comment: I think (guess) it must be something with the event.preventDefault(); but I don't know how and where to add this in my code...

Comment: No, in this case event.preventDefault() just prevent the the default action to be triggered, in your case the form will not be submited and refresh the page, I tested your code and not getting any error, lets try to clear the cache and see what happen, open the developers tools and go to the network tab then check "disable cache " checkbox and then refresh your site.

Comment: Ok, last try, I think that I have found your issue,  your jquery lib it's not being loaded from the cdn for some reason. Try to paste this url in your browser and check if it's loading (CDN)[cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js], you can also check this in the developers tools in the network tab and see if you are receiving 404 from the cdn that you already have in your script

Comment: Hi Jarguez01. Your last post did the thing indeed. The lib.js was not loading. Error in the path (very stupid error). I updated the code in this post. Now it's working. Hope it may serve other people too one day. Thank you very much ! Anna